# How do I change attributes of a model after a set time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activejob

I have a timer class in my application set to expire 24 hours after creation.

Is there a way to run expire_if_running 24 hours after creation date, or do I have to run a cron job every minute?

```
class Timer < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {
    running: 1, # the default
    expired: 2 # timed out
    finished: 3 # completed
  }

  # if the Timer isn't finished, expire it
  def expire_if_running
    self.status = "expired" if self.running?
  end
end
```

Please provide sample code or a citation for your answer. I've never used ActiveJob before, and I have the faint feeling this is the sort of case that requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to run this exact same scenario using `delayed_job`, which is better since it runs at a time in the future.

A cronjob by the minute can be 59 seconds late in expiring the timer.
A cronjob by the hour can be 59 minutes late in expiring the timer.

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/appointment-reminders/ruby/rails#1) from Twilio on how to make a reminder app.

Answer (score 0):

Running a "cron job" is one way of doing it. But instead of running every minute, it would be better to run it every hour, unless there is a specific reason to have 1 minute accuracy.

ActiveJob ([reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html)) is one way to do this. I would recommend Sidekiq because it works great for us. However, without specific info about your environment (Heroku?) I can't specify exactly how to do it.

Comment: We're currently using Heroku in production but we plan to move to our own infrastructure eventually. Doesn't ActiveJob have it's own syntax like ActiveRecord does with it's ORM.

Comment: After reading the docs for ActiveJob, it seems that it runs a task at a specific time in the future. For "cron job" functionality, you can use Heroku scheduler. Write a rake task that will update the status of all expired jobs.